# Pass strings by reference in Powershell?

Tags: function, powershell, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, powershell-3.0

How can I pass strings by reference to the parent scope?

This doesn't work since strings are not acceptable "values".

```
function Submit([ref]$firstName){ 
    $firstName.value =  $txtFirstName.Text 
}

$firstName = $null
Submit([ref]$firstName)
$firstName
```

**Error:** "Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable"

Doing this doesn't give an error but it doesn't change the variable either:

```
$firstName = "nothing"

function Submit([ref]$firstName){ 
    $firstName =  $txtFirstName.Text 
} 

Submit([ref]$firstName)
$firstName
```

## Edit:

Doing the first code block by itself works. However when trying to do it in my script it returns the error again. I fixed it enough for it to assign the variable and do what I want but it still throws up an error and I was wondering how to fix that. I think it's because it doesn't like variable;es changing during a running session. Here is a link to my script

https://github.com/InconspicuousIntern/Form/blob/master/Form.ps1

Comment: I posted an "answer" below.  I'll work with you there via the comments.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a string by reference? A function can output a string.

Comment: Your 1st snippet is conceptually correct and should work as-is (verified in v5.1, but I wouldn't expect v3 to act differently, unless there's a bug). That the 2nd snippet doesn't work is to be expected, because by assigning to `$firstName` directly you're creating a _new_ `[ref]` instance.

Comment: I have multiple strings. Better ways of doing this are welcome. Doing the first code block by itself works. However doing it in my code returns the error again. I fixed it enough for it to assign the variable and do what I want but it still throws up an error and I was wondering how to fix that. Here is my whole script https://github.com/InconspicuousIntern/Form/blob/master/Form.ps1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your first snippet is conceptually correct and works as intended** - by itself it does *not* produce the "Property 'Value' cannot be found on this object" error.

You're seeing the error only as part of the full script you link to, because of the following line:

```
$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ Submit })
```

This line causes your `Submit` function to be called *without arguments*, which in turn causes the `$firstName` parameter value to be `$null`, which in turn causes the error quoted above when you assign to `$firstName.Value`.

By contrast, the following invocation of `Submit`, as in your first snippet, is correct:

```
Submit ([ref] $firstName)  # Note the recommended space after 'Submit' - see below.
```

`[ref] $firstName` creates a (transient) reference to the caller's `$firstName` *variable*, which inside `Submit` binds to (local) *parameter variable* `$firstName` (the two may, but needn't and perhaps better not have the same name), where `$firstName.Value` can then be used to modify the caller's `$firstName` variable.

---

**Syntax note**: I've intentionally placed a space between `Submit` and `([ref] $firstName)` to make one thing clearer:

The `(...)` (parentheses) here do not enclose the entire argument *list*, as they would in a *method* call, they enclose the *single argument* `[ref] $firstName` - of necessity, because that *expression* wouldn't be recognized as such otherwise.

Function calls in PowerShell are parsed in so-called *argument mode*, whose syntax is more like that of invoking console applications: arguments are *space*-separated, and generally only need quoting if they contain special characters.

For instance, if you also wanted to pass string `'foo'`, as the 2nd positional parameter, to `Submit`:

```
Submit ([ref] $firstName) foo
```

Note how the two arguments are space-separated and how `foo` needn't be quoted.

---

As for an **alternative approach**:

`[ref]`'s primary purpose is to enable .NET method calls that have `ref` / `out` parameters, and, as shown above, using `[ref]` is nontrivial.

For calls to PowerShell functions there are generally simpler solutions.

For instance, you can pass a *custom object* to your function and let the function update its properties with the values you want to return, which naturally allows *multiple* values to be "returned"; e.g.:

```
function Submit($outObj){ 
    $outObj.firstName = 'a first name'
}

# Initialize the custom object that will receive values inside
# the Submit function.
$obj = [pscustomobject] @{ firstName = $null }

# Pass the custom object to Submit.
# Since a custom object is a reference type, a *reference* to it
# is bound to the $outObj parameter variable.
Submit $obj

$obj.firstName # -> 'a first name'
```

Alternatively, you can just let `Submit` construct the custom object itself, and simply *output* it:

```
function Submit { 
    # Construct and (implicitly) output a custom
    # object with all values of interest.
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
        firstName = 'a first name' 
    } 
}

$obj = Submit

$obj.firstName # -> 'a first name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out and see if you are getting the same results?  It is working for me, and I really did not change much.

```
$txtFirstName = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Text = "Something"
}

function Submit([ref]$var){ 
    $var.value =  $txtFirstName.Text 
}



$firstName = $null
Submit([ref]$firstName)
$firstName
```

Comment: Your answer should have been a comment: The OP's original code (1st snippet) _should_ work, and the symptom he describes does not match the code. I suggest conducting the conversation in comments until the question no longer falls into the "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" closure category.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . . . I preferred an answer for the code formatting.