# Pass by reference appears to work but still generates an error? How do I return multiple values from a WinForms dialog?

Tags: winforms, function, powershell, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

**Background**

I am trying to make a WinForm that when the user hits the "Submit" button, all the values in the Submit function are returned to the main to be worked with. For testing purposes, I've just been trying to get `$firstName` to work. To do this I've been trying to figure out pass by reference parameters.

**This block of code works by itself:**

```
$txtFirstName = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtFirstName.text = "John"

function Submit([ref]$firstName){ 
    $firstName.value =  $txtFirstName.Text 
}

$firstName = $null
Submit([ref]$firstName)
$firstName
```

However, when I try to apply the same concept to my [script](https://github.com/InconspicuousIntern/Form/blob/master/Form.ps1) it appears to work **BUT** I still get an error.

**Error:**

> Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.

#### Here's my script:

https://github.com/InconspicuousIntern/Form/blob/master/Form.ps1

**My hypothesis:**

1. PowerShell has a problem with passing/assigning variables while running.
2. My script is out of order (I'm not used to functions having to be defined first)

Comment: Why do you need to pass by reference? Functions output values.

Comment: I'm returning a bunch of strings. It's been years since I've programmed but that's how I remember doing things in C++. If you look at my code I basically want as soon as the Submit button is hit, all the information in the textfields and so forth will be assigned to a variable. That way in main and other functions I can just reference `$FirstName` instead of `txtFirstName.text`. I've asked for other ways to do this and people suggested assigning objects or making them global but this is what I'm most familiar with and I've gotten some success with it while not entirely understanding the others

Comment: I think you need to learn a bit more about how PowerShell works. A PowerShell function can return (output) a list of strings.

Comment: Yes I do. Reading material would be nice. I originally started with things like `return $firstname` but it seemed to just return the value and not the actual variable when calling the function. Everyone else seemed to think making it Global or an object was the way to go.

Comment: Search engines can be quite useful in finding good reading materials. There are books available also. As you have noticed, it is frustrating when things "don't work" but this is due to fundamental misunderstandings. You need to learn to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your original snippet works and why your linked full script does *not* work is covered in [my answer to your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105621/45375).

In short: you had an event handler that called your `Submit` function *without arguments* first, in *addition to* later calling it correctly *with* an argument, which caused the issue.

---

**As for the explanation in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51105597/45375)**:

Your rearranged code only works *accidentally*:

It attaches the event handler that contains the flawed, argument-less `Submit` call *after* the dialog has been displayed, at which point it simply does nothing.

---

**How to structure your code:**

You have two basic options, which are commonly *combined*:

- Take action *while the dialog is being displayed*, using *event handlers*.

  - You attach event handlers as script blocks passed to individual controls' `.Add_<eventName>()` methods, as you did in the case of `$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ ... })`.
  - Caveat: The script block runs in a *child variable scope*, so extra work is needed in order to modify variables in the caller's scope, such as using the `script` scope specifier; e.g., `$script:var` (or even using the `[ref]` approach, but that is heavy-handed).
- Take action *after the dialog has closed*.

  - You can then simply access the form controls' properties directly.

The following self-contained snippet demonstrates both techniques:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create the form.
$form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    ClientSize      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 400,100
    Text            = "Dialog Demo"
}    

# Create the controls and add them to the form.
$form.Controls.AddRange(@(
    New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label -Property @{
        Text           = "First Name:"
        AutoSize       = $true
        Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 10,20
        Font           = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
    }

    ($txtFirstName = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox -Property @{
        Width          = 250
        Location       = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 100, 20
    })

    ($btnSubmit = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
        Text              = "Submit"
        Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point 160, 60
    })
))


# Attach an event handler to the first-name field.
$txtFirstName.Add_KeyPress({ param($obj, $evArgs)
    # Example: Convert every character typed to uppercase. 
    $evArgs.KeyChar = [char]::ToUpper($evArgs.KeyChar)
})

# Make pressing Enter the same as clicking the Submit button.
$form.AcceptButton = $btnSubmit
# Make the Submit button act like an OK button, which means:
#  - auto-close the form
#  - make .ShowDialog() return [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$btnSubmit.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

# Show the form synchronously (during which event handlers may fire)
# and take action based on the return value, which is
# a [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult] enumeration value that
# reflects the button used to close the form.
if ($form.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') { # Dialog was confirmed.

    # You can now access the controls' properties as needed.
    # In this example we output a custom object that contains
    # the first name; this can easily be extended to include
    # other properties
    [pscustomobject] @{
        FirstName = $txtFirstName.Text 
    }

} else { # Dialog was canceled.
    Write-Warning "Dialog canceled."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** Script components were out of order.

Needed to be:

```
function Submit(){...}

<form fields>

[void]$NewUserForm.ShowDialog()
Submit([ref]$firstName)
$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ Submit }) #GUI event
$firstName
```

Instead of:

```
function Submit(){...}

<form fields>

$btnSubmit.Add_Click({ Submit }) #GUI event
[void]$NewUserForm.ShowDialog()
Submit([ref]$firstName)  
$firstName
```

If anyone has links to where I can learn more about how to order my scripts and methods for doing so I would be grateful.